# The conceptual relation between independent random variables and independent events

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Have a look at the question:

Let $N(t)$ be a Poisson process with intensity $\lambda=2$, and let $X_1, X_2, \cdots$ be the corresponding interarrival times. Given that the third arrival occurred at time $t=2$, find the probability that the fourth arrival occurs after $t=4$.

I feel that $$
\begin{aligned}
P\left(X_4>2 \mid X_1+X_2+X_3=2\right) & =P\left(X_4>2\right) \\
& =e^{-2 \times 2} \\
\end{aligned}
$$
due to the independence of $X_i$'s. but how can I claim the events $X_4>2$ and $X_1+X_2+X_3=2$ are independent?

In general can I say ''$X$ and $Y+Z$ are independent when $X,Y,$ and $Z$ are independent''?

Can I try with $P(A|B \cap C \cap D)=\frac{P(A \cap B \cap C \cap D)}{P(B \cap C)}$?, where $A:~X_4>2$, $B:~X_1=a,~C:~X_2=b,$ and $D:~X_3=c $, with $a+b+c=2$, Again how to write the numerator as $P(A)P(B \cap C \cap D)$?

Comment: Hi: I think you have a typo: "I feel that P(X > 2)" should be "I feel that P(X > 4)".   As far as your question, have the lectures or textbook discussed the independent increments property of the poisson or the memoryless property of the exponential ? You can use either of those to justify your reasoning.

Comment: @markleeds note that $X_i$'s are interarrival times (time laps between arrivals).

Comment: Hi Messi Lio : Yes, if the $N(t)$ are Poisson, then the interarrival times exponentially distributed.  The idea is that, because of the memoryless property of the exponential, $X_{4} - X_{3}$ is exponentially distributed with the same parameter, $\lambda = 2$. So the probability that $X_4$ is greater than 4 given that sum of the first three $X_{i}$ are 2,  is the same as the probability $X_{i} > (4 - 2) =  2 ~  \forall ~ i $.

Comment: Also, you still have the typo that I mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: @markleeds I am not getting the random variable $X$ in your comment ''I feel that $P(X > 4)$".

Comment: Hi: If you just showed up and wanted to calculate the probability that $X_{4} > 4$ then it's okay to write $P(X_{4} > 4)$. But, given that $X_{3}$ occurred at $t = 2$, then 2 units of time have already passed. So, for $X_{4}$ to be greater than 4, it only has to occur 2 units or more later than $X_{3}$. Do you have a book on stochastic processes such as Ross ? All the material you need about the exponential should be in there ?